# How to avoid uploading same image if it already exists on S3 using scrapy image pipeline?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project which extracts product data and images from a website on daily basis.

Images are being uploaded directly to Amazon S3. Product images rarely change for any product. So, I don't want to upload same images to S3 every day when the script runs.

Is there a way to check if image already exists on S3 and avoid uploading the same image again and again?

I'm using scrapy `ImagePipline` to upload images to S3 directly from the image url from the website I'm **scraping**. Not downloading images locally on my server.